# how to connect Files table with other tables that might upload files?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have 4 entities in my project: Project, Task, Comment, AttachedFile

In first 3 entities the user can attach files to them i think it's one to many relationship, So I introduce navigation property in the them:

```
public List<AttachedFiles> AttachedFiles {get; set;}
```

After doing Initial migration EFCore created 3 FK in the AttachedFiles table, i think this is a bad design because in the future I might consider uploading files from extra sources and every time it will add new FK to the table, also it will be hard to maintain the table in the long run. Also another developer might fill 2 FKs for the same row when every file should relate to one source.

I found 2 solutions:

1. Intorduce OwnedId, OwnedType proparities in the AttachedFiles table and when insert fill the type with the PK for the source.

However it will introduce more problems: there won't be a explicit relation between those tables and I couldn't introduce navigation property to benefit from EFCore so I must write all commands and queries manually, Also if the PK removed the files will still be available (No cascade action on Delete).

2. Introduce 3 more entities that sets between the source and attached file. this way I will have no problem with EFCore, but i think the relation will be many to many instead of one to many.

Anyone have suggestions or solution to this problem or if I could use the first solution with EFCore?

Answer (score 0):

> Introduce 3 more entities that sets between the source and attached file. this way I will have no problem with EFCore, but i think the relation will be many to many instead of one to many.

If you don't want a many-to-many relationship, then the three entities you indroduce should be PorojectAttachedFile, UserAttachedFile, and CommentAttachedFile.  These can all inherit from a base AttachedFile class that either is not an Entity, or uses TPT inheritance in the database.